# requests.post is not giving any response in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, call

I'm using Python requests 2.19.1 . 
But I'm facing an intermittent issue where I get no response at all when I post to a specific url.

I'm trying to check if the LDAP is giving me the expected output for invalid credentials.
Here's the format:

```
requests.post('https://oxhp-member.uhc.com/Member/MemberPortal/j_acegi_security_check',
              credentials_payload)
```

that I'm posting

Almost everytime, it works fine. But sometimes, it doesn't give any response for that. Even network issues gives us some response. Right? Why am I not getting any response for the above call.

Is there any existing bug in requests?

Somebody please point me in correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` is not responsible for "giving back response". The server you are using `requests` to post to is.

To see the response you have to keep it in a variable and handle it somehow.

```
resp = requests.post('https://oxhp-member.uhc.com/Member/MemberPortal/j_acegi_security_check',
                     credentials_payload)

print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.content)
```

Whatever `resp` contains is the responsibility of the server.